# How to show value in a dropdown option field in laravel?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I have 3 table **hosts** **visitors** and **visitor_types**. I wand to show **host name** and **visitor type** in a drop down option button. But I am little bit confused about the *controller* and *route* code. I write the code code that is given below but it's show -Undefined variable: host *(View: C:\laragon\www\ves\resources\views\admin\visitor.blade.php)*

```
Controller Code: VisitorController.php


  <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Visitor;
use App\Host;
use App\visitorType;
use App\visitors;
use App\hosts;
use App\visitorTypes;
use App\visitor_s;

class VisitorController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware("auth");
    }
    // View All Visitor
public function index() {

    $visitor = Visitor::all();
    return view('admin\visitor', compact('visitor'));
}
// Taking all host data
public function optionValue() {
    $hosts = Host::all();
    return view('admin\host', compact('hosts'));
}


    Model : Visitor.php
    <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Visitor extends Model
{
//
public function hosts(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Host');
}
public function visitorTypes(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\VisitorType');
}
}

Model: Host.php




  <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Host extends Model
{
//
public function visitors(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Visitor');
}

}

View Code: visitor.blade.php

<select class="form-control input-medium" name="host">
  @foreach($hosts as $host)
   <option value="{{ $host->name }}">{{ $host->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
```

```
Route code: web.php
Route::get('/vsistor','VisitorController@optionValue')->name('optionValue');
```

In visitor table the **host_id** and **vType_id** is foreign key from *host* and visitor_types table. 
 So how can I display **Name** that comes from another table in a drop down button?

Comment: I think your mistake is there : @foreach($host as $host) same variable name

Comment: But I display the host table value in using @foreach($host as $host). That's work fine.

Comment: Now I changes the variable name but it's showing same error.

Comment: You have some typos: 1. Your @endforeach ends  outside the </select tag>, so the items will not displayed correctly. 2. You may have a typo in your route: `/vsistor` 2. As @Ts8060 says, your foreach array must be named different to the key/value of the array like `$hosts as $host`

Comment: And $visitor->name is printed as string... But i can not find why $host is undefined. Maybe your sharing code is different from your local

Comment: I just copy from my local code and paste here. But I am also confused why I show undefined variable?

Comment: Now I change my code as you suggested and it's showing Undefined variable: host (View: C:\laragon\www\ves\resources\views\admin\visitor.blade.php)

Comment: Please, Can any one gives me any example to print the foreign key value in drop down button?  @Dennis and Ts8060

Comment: You have to change the variables in your `hostController ` to `$hosts`

Comment: Yes. public function optionValue(){

        $hosts = host::all();
        return view('admin\visitor', compact('hosts'));
    }

Comment: Okay, you updated the code, right, what exactly is now the problem? Or is everything fine now

Comment: I updated my code. but it's showing same error. Undefined variable: hosts (View: C:\laragon\www\ves\resources\views\admin\visitor.blade.php)

Comment: Is there any problem in route?

Comment: Can you print in top of your blade the $posts variable? {{ dd($posts) }} . if it returns the object, than the route is fine

Comment: What Larvel version u are using? maybe the return in the controller is wrong and should be: `return view('admin\visitor')->with(compact('hosts'));`

Comment: I am using current version laravel 5.6

Comment: @Md.AbuZaman is the data showing up when you `dd($hosts)` in your blade?

Comment: No. But now I updated my code with the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index() {
    
    $visitor = Visitor::all();
    $hosts = Host::all();
    $visitorType = VisitorType::all();
    return view('admin\visitor', compact('hosts','visitorType','visitor'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes.

1) You send $host variable to view but you use as $hosts in foreach loop on view.
You can set your code as this

```
$hosts = host::all();
return view('admin\visitor', compact('hosts'));
```

2) You must use {{ }} for printing variable on view.

```
<option value="{{ $host->name }}">{{ $host->name}}</option>
```

Ps: Actually model name must start with uppercase(host::all() -> Host::all())

Comment: I rename model name and model class but still same error.

Comment: $hosts = Host::all();
       return view('admin\visitor', compact('hosts'));

Comment: Did you change value attribute of option tag? You didn't write brackets (value="$host->name") but this must be value="{{ $host->name }}"  
@Md.AbuZaman